# Insertar data.sql en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, h2

Hola tengo una clase Estudiante Entity bastante sencilla que se añade a base de datos es un CRUD muy básico con H2.

En application.properties tengo la siguiente configuración

```
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:db/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:db/data.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
server.port=8080
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:memDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/fileDb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.properties.hibernate.format_slq=true
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

El archivo data.sql son unos inserts de estudiante son los siguientes:

```
INSERT INTO ESTUDIANTE (NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES ('Juan','Torres',20);
INSERT INTO ESTUDIANTE (NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES ('Maria','Gomez',27);
INSERT INTO ESTUDIANTE (NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES ('Eva','Gonzalez',21);
INSERT INTO ESTUDIANTE (NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD) VALUES ('Carlos','Pedraza',30);
COMMIT;
```

y el schema.sql que crea la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE ESTUDIANTE(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NOMBRE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   APELLIDO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   EDAD INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Lo que no consigo hacer es que me cargue el script, Spring Boot con esos inserts ya añadidos a la base de datos, este es mi main.

```
package com.example.Ejercicio3SpringBootinferfecejpa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Ejercicio3SpringBootInferfeceJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Ejercicio3SpringBootInferfeceJpaApplication.class, args);
        EstudianteRepository repository = context.getBean(EstudianteRepository.class);

        Estudiante estudiante1 = new Estudiante("Maria Fernanda", "Gonzalez", 40);
        Estudiante estudiante2 = new Estudiante("Luna", "Gonzalez", 46);
        Estudiante estudiante3 = new Estudiante("Carlos", "Paredes", 43);

        repository.save(estudiante1);
        repository.save(estudiante2);
        repository.save(estudiante3);

        System.out.println("Estudiantes en la bbdd " +repository.count());


    }


}
```

¿Qué me falta en application.properties para que me cargue el script?

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: en que ruta relativa al proyecto pones tu schema.sql? que sistema de construccio usas maven?

Comment: Buenas si uso maven, la ruta relativa que uso es la siguiente Ejercicio3-SpringBoot-inferfece-jpa\src\main\resources dentro de la carpeta resources tengo una carpeta llamada db en ella tengo data.sql y el schema.sql, data inserta los datos y en el schema.sql tengo la creación de la tabla de todas formas me tengo que poner a mirar que esta pasando por que tengo que hacer algo parecido pero con REST, intentaré a obtener la ruta raíz del proyecto a ver si lo soluciono. Gracias y Feliz año :)

Comment: la parte de rest nunca la mencionas en la pregunta, yo creo que te puedes autoresponder con los dos nombres de archivos y que deben de ir en la carpeta resources, ya que esto es un estandard en spring; ahora para lo de rest te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que se intentan insertar los registros del main antes que los cambios en la base de datos estén terminados.
Para lograr que la aplicación se inicie luego de ejecutar el script de actualización de datos puedes agregar la siguiente línea en tu *application.properties*:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

> if you want script-based DataSource initialization to be able to
> build upon the schema creation performed by Hibernate, set
> spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true

Un detalle que veo y tal vez te sirva, `spring.datasource.data` está deprecado, deberías reemplazarlo con

```
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:db/data.sql
```

Comment: Gracias por la contestación aunque sea tarde, lo conseguí hacer y era exactamente eso